# How to get all rows during a day with a specific column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple rows in a table with a column named "created" that has a timestamp in the format **"1309494407"**. I need to do a SQL query to get how many rows there are that has a certain value of column called "category" with the value of **"book"**. Basically I need to know how many books are created every day in the database.

How is this accomplished with PostgreSQL?

**My schema:**

```
Items(id, category, created)
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_schema.items
WHERE
    (category = 'books' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(created) < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 days')
```

And it doesn't work I get problem:

> function to_timestamp(character varying) does not exist

Comment: what is your postgres version?

Comment: If you want the results for every day, why are you filtering the data?  This sounds like an aggregation query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I need to know how many books are created every day in the database.

Your timestamp looks like a Unix epoch.  If so, you can get what you want using simple arithmetic:

```
SELECT floor(i.created / (24 * 60 * 60)) as dy, COUNT(*)
FROM my_schema.items i
WHERE i.category = 'books' 
GROUP BY dy;
```

If you like, you can convert it to a calendar date using:

```
SELECT '1970-01-01' + floor(i.created / (24 * 60 * 60)) * interval '1 day' as dy, COUNT(*)
FROM my_schema.items i
WHERE i.category = 'books' 
GROUP BY dy;
```

Comment: I have the impression OP wants the books added in the last 24 hours.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . It is confusing.  The text and the query don't match very well at all.

Answer (score 0):

What a wonder example of why Unix epoch is such a poor choice for storing dates, and a text representation of the number at that. Always store dates/timestamps with the appropriate type. If needed the epoch is easily retrieved from a date, but deriving the date from epoch is - well ugly. And actual timestamp even uglier. 
If you happen to to be on version 12 you can at least capture the date in a table column itself, without having to change the code already using the existing column. Create a generated column that derives the actual date. (Guess that would make an interesting round trip, given a date derive the epoch then given the epoch derive the date).

```
alter table items 
  add created_date date generated always as 
      ('1970-01-01'::timestamp + (created::integer/ 86400) * interval '1 day')  
  stored;
```

Now this query reduces itself to the simple and straight forward:

```
select i.created_date,count(*)
  from my_schema.items i
 where i.category = 'books' 
 group by i.created_date
 order by i.created_date;
```

It also has the additional benefit of making all the Postgres date handling functions available.